# Refreshing access tokens in IdentityServer4 clients

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openid-connect, identityserver4

I wonder how to refresh a access token in a IdentityServer4 client using the hybrid flow and which is built using ASP.NET Core MVC.

If I have understood the whole concept correctly the client first need to have the "offline_access" scope in order to be able to use refresh tokens which is best practice to enable short lived access tokens and ability to revoke refresh tokens preventing any new access tokens to be issued to the client.

I successfully get a access token and a refresh token, but how should I handle the actual update procedure of the access token in the MVC client?

Can the OpenId Connect (OIDC) middleware handle this automatically? Or should I rather check the expire time of the access token everywhere I call WEB Api's by basically check if the access token have expired or will expire very soon (upcoming 30 seconds) then refresh the access token by calling the token endpoint using the refresh token?

Is it recommended to use the [IdentityModel2](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel2) library `TokenClient` extension method `RequestRefreshTokenAsync` in my Controller action methods for calling the token endpoint?

I have seen code that in the OIDC middleware events request access token and using the response store a claim containing a expire datetime. The problem is that my OIDC in somehow already request a access token automatically so it doesn't feel good to request a new access token directly after recieving the first one.

Example of a Controller action method **without** access token refresh logic:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetInvoices()
    {
        var token = await HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.SetBearerToken(token);

        var response = await client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:5001/api/getInvoices");
        ViewBag.Json = JArray.Parse(response).ToString();

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The OIDC middleware will **not** take care of this for you. It's being executed when it detects a `HTTP 401` response, it then redirects the user to IdentityServer login page. After the redirection to your MVC application, it will turn claims into a `ClaimsIdentity` and pass this on to the Cookies middleware which will materialise that into a session cookie.

Every other request will not involve the OIDC middleware as long as the cookie is still valid.

So you have to take care of this yourself. Another thing you want to consider is that whenever you're going to refresh the access token, you'll have to update the existing one so you don't lose it. If you don't do this, the session cookie will always contain the same token - the original one - and you'll refresh it every time.

A solution I found is to hook that into the Cookies middleware.
Here's the general flow:

- On every request, use the Cookies middleware events to inspect the access token
- If it's close to its expiration time, request a new one
- Replace the new access and refresh tokens in the `ClaimsIdentity`
- Instruct the Cookies middleware to renew the session cookie so it contains the new tokens

What I like with this approach is that in your MVC code, you're pretty much guaranteed to always have a valid access token, unless refereshing the token keeps failing several times in a row.

What I don't like is that it's very tied to MVC - more specifically the Cookies middleware - so it's not really portable.

You can have a look at [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/mderriey/TokenRenewal/blob/master/src/MvcClient/Startup.cs) I put together. It indeed uses `IdentityModel` as this takes care of everything and hides most of the complexity of the HTTP calls you'd have to make to IdentityServer.

Comment: Great solution, any thoughts on if this code supports multiple concurrent HTTP requests by a specific user? Will there be a race for access token renewal and refresh tokens be invalidated if not using RefreshTokenUsage.ReUse in the client settings? Also any ideas on how Ajax calls in javascript code should handle renewal of access token?

Comment: Thanks. For concurrent calls, I'd recommend using a solution that automatically handles token renewal and expiration, like [this simple but very handy .NET wrapper](https://github.com/filipw/async-expiring-lazy). For JavaScript, I'd suggest [`oidc-client-js`](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) created by Brock Allen. Then the integration in your app from HTTP calls will depend on what framework you use.

Comment: Very interesting thanks! I found the blog article written by the developer here https://www.strathweb.com/2016/11/lazy-async-initialization-for-expiring-objects/

Comment: Now I need to figure out where to place the code, I'm thinking somekind of service class which can be injected everywhere needed. The question is how to wire up the class in the IOC container in order to separate each instance for each user?

Comment: If I had to do it, I'd store the tokens in a secure session cookie. Then you feed the async lazy with the existing token. If it's still OK to use, fine. If not, the wrapper could renew it and replace the  tokens in the cookie (meaning issuing a new cookie to the browser). As for the  A IPC registration, a per-HTTP-request lifetime should work just fine.

Comment: Would make sense to modify this solution and make the client authentication cookie a session cookie (still containing the identity/claims, access_token and refresh_token) and still having a expiriation time of let say 12 hours. I'm not very found of persistent cookies, letting them be logged on for 12 hours or until they close the browser is better. A custom claim type "expire_at" with access_token expire time could replace the logic of knowing when it's time to refresh the access_token. Do you think your solution work with the OIDC hybrid flow?

Comment: When using reference tokens (opaque access tokens) I'm not sure if this solution works, any thougths?

Comment: I'd say at this point it comes down to how you want to implement things. Opaque tokens won't have an impact as long as you keep track of the expiry date when the token is renewed. Same thing for the flow; as long as it allows you to get refresh tokens, it will work. What type of cookie and how you store the tokens and the expiry date is up to you. Makes sense?

Comment: Great code you have in the github repo, one thing I have discovered is that this code isn't good for a ASP.NET Core MVC web application which uses many AJAX requests on each page.

The users stays on a page for a long time using functionality relying on AJAX requests, the access token expires and the requests fails. The users first need to refresh the whole page in order to make a "normal" request to the web application which then renews the access token.

Comment: Regarding my last comment, I'm thinking about developing a action filter which is registered as an global filter in my MVC application and which handles the renewal of access tokens. If you compare against the cookie middleware solution, thinking of any cons?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to instruct the cookie middleware to send a new cookie (with the renewed access token) to the client from an action filter.

Comment: I managed to find a working solution based on filter, see my answer below for some sample code, I have another more updated version aswell.

Comment: Hi @MickaëlDerriey, I look at the code and do not understand one point is that. After you replace(set ShoudRenew = true) cookies with new `access token` and `refresh token`. You do not reset the expiration time of the cookie, why? So I saw on `OnTokenValidated` Event you said the cookie's expiration time to be same as `access token`. Let say the `access token` will expire in next 1 hour and when you renew it on `OnValidatePrincipal` you still have a expired cookie, right? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When requesting the cookie to be renewed, the ASP.NET cookie middleware creates a cookie with a new expiration date. It is valid from the moment it's created and expires based on the lifetime of the existing cookie. See [the implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs#L88-L102) in the official repository.

Answer (score 2):

I created a solution based on a action filter togheter with the OIDC middleware in ASP.NET Core 2.0.

AJAX requests will also go via the action filter hence update the access token/refresh token.

https://gist.github.com/devJ0n/43c6888161169e09fec542d2dc12af09

Answer (score 0):

I found two possible solutions, both are equal but happens at different times in the OIDC middleware. In the events I extract the access token expire time value and store it as a claim which later can be used to check if it's OK to call an Web API with the current access token or if I rather should request a new access token using the refresh token.

I would appreciate if someone could give any input on which of these events are preferable to use.

```
var oidcOptions = new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
      AuthenticationScheme = appSettings.OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationScheme,
      SignInScheme = appSettings.OpenIdConnect.SignInScheme,

      Authority = appSettings.OpenIdConnect.Authority,
      RequireHttpsMetadata = _hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment() ? false : true,
      PostLogoutRedirectUri = appSettings.OpenIdConnect.PostLogoutRedirectUri,

      ClientId = appSettings.OpenIdConnect.ClientId,
      ClientSecret = appSettings.OpenIdConnect.ClientSecret,
      ResponseType = appSettings.OpenIdConnect.ResponseType,

      UseTokenLifetime = appSettings.OpenIdConnect.UseTokenLifetime,
      SaveTokens = appSettings.OpenIdConnect.SaveTokens,
      GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = appSettings.OpenIdConnect.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint,

      Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
      {
          OnTicketReceived = TicketReceived,
          OnUserInformationReceived = UserInformationReceived
      },

      TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
      {                    
          NameClaimType = appSettings.OpenIdConnect.NameClaimType,
          RoleClaimType = appSettings.OpenIdConnect.RoleClaimType
      }
  };
  oidcOptions.Scope.Clear();
  foreach (var scope in appSettings.OpenIdConnect.Scopes)
  {
      oidcOptions.Scope.Add(scope);
  }
  app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(oidcOptions);
```

And here is some event examples I'm can choose among:

```
        public async Task TicketReceived(TicketReceivedContext trc)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("TicketReceived");

            //Alternatives to get the expires_at value
            //var expiresAt1 = trc.Ticket.Properties.GetTokens().SingleOrDefault(t => t.Name == "expires_at").Value;
            //var expiresAt2 = trc.Ticket.Properties.GetTokenValue("expires_at");
            //var expiresAt3 = trc.Ticket.Properties.Items[".Token.expires_at"];

            //Outputs:
            //expiresAt1 = "2016-12-19T11:58:24.0006542+00:00"
            //expiresAt2 = "2016-12-19T11:58:24.0006542+00:00"
            //expiresAt3 = "2016-12-19T11:58:24.0006542+00:00"

            //Remove OIDC protocol claims ("iss","aud","exp","iat","auth_time","nonce","acr","amr","azp","nbf","c_hash","sid","idp")
            ClaimsPrincipal p = TransformClaims(trc.Ticket.Principal);

            //var identity = p.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

            // keep track of access token expiration
            //identity.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_at1", expiresAt1.ToString()));
            //identity.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_at2", expiresAt2.ToString()));
            //identity.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_at3", expiresAt3.ToString()));

            //Todo: Check if it's OK to replace principal instead of the ticket, currently I can't make it work when replacing the whole ticket.
            //trc.Ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(p, trc.Ticket.Properties, trc.Ticket.AuthenticationScheme);
            trc.Principal = p;                
        });
    }
```

I also have the UserInformationReceived event, I'm not sure if I should use this instead of the TicketReceived event.

```
        public async Task UserInformationReceived(UserInformationReceivedContext uirc)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("UserInformationReceived");

            ////Alternatives to get the expires_at value
            //var expiresAt4 = uirc.Ticket.Properties.GetTokens().SingleOrDefault(t => t.Name == "expires_at").Value;
            //var expiresAt5 = uirc.Ticket.Properties.GetTokenValue("expires_at");
            //var expiresAt6 = uirc.Ticket.Properties.Items[".Token.expires_at"];
            //var expiresIn1 = uirc.ProtocolMessage.ExpiresIn;

            //Outputs:
            //expiresAt4 = "2016-12-19T11:58:24.0006542+00:00"
            //expiresAt5 = "2016-12-19T11:58:24.0006542+00:00"
            //expiresAt6 = "2016-12-19T11:58:24.0006542+00:00"
            //expiresIn = "60" <-- The 60 seconds test interval for the access token lifetime is configured in the IdentityServer client configuration settings

            var identity = uirc.Ticket.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

            //Keep track of access token expiration
            //Add a claim with information about when the access token is expired, it's possible that I instead should use expiresAt4, expiresAt5 or expiresAt6 
            //instead of manually calculating the expire time.
            //This claim will later be checked before calling Web API's and if needed a new access token will be requested via the IdentityModel2 library.
            //identity.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_at4", expiresAt4.ToString()));
            //identity.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_at5", expiresAt5.ToString()));
            //identity.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_at6", expiresAt6.ToString()));
            //identity.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_in1", expiresIn1.ToString()));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_in", DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(uirc.ProtocolMessage.ExpiresIn)).ToLocalTime().ToString()));
            //identity.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_in3", DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(uirc.ProtocolMessage.ExpiresIn)).ToString()));

            //The following is not needed when to OIDC middleware CookieAuthenticationOptions.SaveTokens = true
            //identity.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", uirc.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));
            //identity.Claims.Append(new Claim("refresh_token", uirc.ProtocolMessage.RefreshToken));
            //identity.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", uirc.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));                
        });
    }
```

Comment: I'm afraid this will not work. The reason for this is that the OIDC middleware will be executed only once when there's an unauthorized request detected. After the user has logged in, the authentication information will be stored in a cookie (driven by the `SignInScheme` property of the `OpenIdConnectOptions`). This means that the OIDC middleware events will be executed once, just after the user has logged in at the IdP. The access token will never be expired at this time. I suggest that you put breakpoints in both the OIDC and cookie middlewares events to see how things work.

Comment: Thanjs for the feedback, please see my other answer above which actually works.