# IdentityServer4 client - Refreshing access tokens on CookieAuthenticationEvents

Tags: authentication, cookies, identityserver4, asp.net-core-middleware

I am trying to use refresh token when the access token expires. A similar so question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41557598/3501052). And [a sample code to renew token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741982/identityserver4-using-refresh-tokens-after-following-the-quickstart-for-hybrid) by an action

And i end up with the following code in the startup.cs

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
    //ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100),
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
    {
        OnValidatePrincipal = async x =>
        {
            if (x.Properties?.Items[".Token.expires_at"] == null) return;

            var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(this.GetType());

            var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
            var tokenExpireTime = DateTime.Parse(x.Properties.Items[".Token.expires_at"]).ToUniversalTime();
            var timeElapsed = now.Subtract(x.Properties.IssuedUtc.Value);
            var timeRemaining = tokenExpireTime.Subtract(now.DateTime);

            if (timeElapsed > timeRemaining)
            {
                var httpContextAuthentication = x.HttpContext.Authentication;//Donot use the HttpContext.Authentication to retrieve anything, this cause recursive call to this event
                var oldAccessToken = await httpContextAuthentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
                var oldRefreshToken = await httpContextAuthentication.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token");
                logger.LogInformation($"Refresh token :{oldRefreshToken}, old access token:{oldAccessToken}");


                var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync(AuthorityServer);
                if (disco.IsError) throw new Exception(disco.Error);

                var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, ApplicationId, "secret");
                var tokenResult = await tokenClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(oldRefreshToken);
                logger.LogInformation("Refresh token requested. " + tokenResult.ErrorDescription);


                if (!tokenResult.IsError)
                {

                    var oldIdToken = await httpContextAuthentication.GetTokenAsync("id_token");
                    var newAccessToken = tokenResult.AccessToken;
                    var newRefreshToken = tokenResult.RefreshToken;

                    var tokens = new List<AuthenticationToken>
                    {
                        new AuthenticationToken {Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.IdToken, Value = oldIdToken},
                        new AuthenticationToken {Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken, Value = newAccessToken},
                        new AuthenticationToken {Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.RefreshToken, Value = newRefreshToken}
                    };

                    var expiresAt = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(tokenResult.ExpiresIn);
                    tokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken { Name = "expires_at", Value = expiresAt.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) });

                    var info = await httpContextAuthentication.GetAuthenticateInfoAsync("Cookies");
                    info.Properties.StoreTokens(tokens);
                    await httpContextAuthentication.SignInAsync("Cookies", info.Principal, info.Properties);

                }
                x.ShouldRenew = true;
            }
            else
            {
                logger.LogInformation("Not expired");
            }
        }

    }
});
```

The client setup is as follows

```
AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse,
RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Sliding,
AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 86400,    
AccessTokenLifetime = 10,
AllowOfflineAccess = true,
AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference
```

After successfully login, i am getting a 401 for every other request. And the log says

> [Identity Server]2017-07-04 10:15:58.819 +01:00 [Debug]
>   "TjpIkvHQi../cfivu6Nql5ADJJlZRuoJV1QI=" found in database: True
>
> [Identity Server]2017-07-04 10:15:58.820 +01:00 [Debug]
>   "reference_token" grant with value:
>   "..9e64c1235c6675fcef617914911846fecd72f7b372" found in store, but has
>   expired.
>
> [Identity Server]2017-07-04 10:15:58.821 +01:00 [Error] Invalid
>   reference token. "{   \"ValidateLifetime\": true,
>   \"AccessTokenType\": \"Reference\",   \"TokenHandle\":
>   \"..9e64c1235c6675fcef617914911846fecd72f7b372\" }"
>
> [Identity Server]2017-07-04 10:15:58.822 +01:00 [Debug] Token is
>   invalid.
>
> [Identity Server]2017-07-04 10:15:58.822 +01:00 [Debug] Creating
>   introspection response for inactive token.
>
> [Identity Server]2017-07-04 10:15:58.822 +01:00 [Information] Success
>   token introspection. Token status: "inactive", for API name: "api1"

Any help would by highly appreciated

**UPDATE**:

Basically, when the token expires i get a `System.StackOverflowException` on the following line

```
var tokenExpireTime = DateTime.Parse(x.Properties.Items[".Token.expires_at"]).ToUniversalTime();
```

**UPDATE 2**:
*Do not use HttpContext.Authentication to retrieve anything*. Check my answer below to find the working implementaion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was working on this for last two days and could not make this work. Funnily, after posting the question here, within 2 hours I make it working :)

```
Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
{
    OnValidatePrincipal = async x =>
    {
        if (x.Properties?.Items[".Token.expires_at"] == null) return;
        var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

        var tokenExpireTime = DateTime.Parse(x.Properties.Items[".Token.expires_at"]).ToUniversalTime();
        var timeElapsed = now.Subtract(x.Properties.IssuedUtc.Value);
        var timeRemaining = tokenExpireTime.Subtract(now.DateTime);
        WriteMessage($"{timeRemaining} and elapsed at {timeElapsed}");
        if (timeElapsed > timeRemaining)
        {
            var oldAccessToken = x.Properties.Items[".Token.access_token"];

            var oldRefreshToken = x.Properties.Items[".Token.refresh_token"];
            WriteMessage($"Refresh token :{oldRefreshToken}, old access token {oldAccessToken}");

            var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync(AuthorityServer);
            if (disco.IsError) throw new Exception(disco.Error);

            var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, ApplicationId, "secret");
            var tokenResult = await tokenClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(oldRefreshToken);

            if (!tokenResult.IsError)
            {
                var oldIdToken = x.Properties.Items[".Token.id_token"];//tokenResult.IdentityToken

                var newAccessToken = tokenResult.AccessToken;
                var newRefreshToken = tokenResult.RefreshToken;

                var tokens = new List<AuthenticationToken>
                {
                    new AuthenticationToken {Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.IdToken, Value = oldIdToken},
                    new AuthenticationToken {Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken, Value = newAccessToken},
                    new AuthenticationToken {Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.RefreshToken, Value = newRefreshToken}
                };

                var expiresAt = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(tokenResult.ExpiresIn);
                tokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken { Name = "expires_at", Value = expiresAt.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) });

                x.Properties.StoreTokens(tokens);

                WriteMessage($"oldAccessToken: {oldAccessToken}{Environment.NewLine} and new access token {newAccessToken}");

            }
            x.ShouldRenew = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically `httpContextAuthentication.GetTokenAsync` make this recursive, for that reason `StackOverflowException` occured.

Please let me know if this implementation has any issue

Comment: Why using the value of oldIdToken instead of tokenResult.IdentityToken when creating the list of AuthenticationTokens?

Comment: @JonasAxelsson Yes, 'tokenResult.IdentityToken` could be used to refresh the IdentityToken as well, but here i was trying to figure out how the refresh token works on IdS4

Comment: Seems like the oldIdToken value differs from the tokenResult.IdentityToken so it's probably better to use the new value which is send togheter with the new tokenResult.AccessToken and tokenResult.RefreshToken